# Display nodes below parent without taking ranks to account

Tags: graphviz, ranking, class-diagram, dot

I'm making sorta super simplified class diagram in [dot](/questions/tagged/dot) language. The diagram contains only simple nodes with class names, inheritance and aggregation.

In order to have a specific style for inheritance edges, and to display children classes below their parent, I use this setup:

```
subgraph inheritance {
    edge[dir="back"; arrowtail="empty"; arrowsize="1.75"];
    color=white;

    subgraph clusterExpression{
        Expression -> VariableExpression;
        Expression -> AssignmentExpression;
```

Everything works fine, but when I have a lot of subclasses my diagram becomes really wide. I don't care about subclasses being on the same level or not.

Is there a way to display all subclasses below superclass but in most compact way? Instead of this: [image]

I want to get something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the graphviz tool called *[unflatten](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/unflatten.1.pdf)* :

> unflatten is a preprocessor to dot that is used to improve the aspect
>   ratio of graphs having many leaves or disconnected nodes. The usual
>   layout for such a graph is generally very wide or tall. unflatten
>   inserts invisible edges or adjusts the minlen on edges to improve
>   layout compaction.

You can pipe it into your command line - see [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11136488/63733) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12372105/63733) for examples.